# Javascript array as object key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
 this.props.onChange({[this.state.searchField]: item.formatted_address.includes(item.name)})
```

Hello what does the above statement resolve to. Does it assigns every element of `this.state.searchField` to the value?

Answer (score 4):

The name of that logic is **[Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax)**.

Basically, is creating an key-value pairs object which key will be the content from `this.state.searchField` and value `item.formatted_address.includes(item.name)` (boolean)

For example:

```js
const myKey = 'ELE';
const myValue = true;
const myObj = {[myKey]: myValue};

console.log(myObj)
```